# Ask interviewee if he/she is has started having lunch / has already eaten or not

Tags: phrase-meaning, exam-questions

I need to create a questionnaire. I have a question with double-choice answer "YES/NO". I want the interviewee to answer:

- Yes: if the interviewee is currently having lunch or the user has already had lunch
- No: if the interviewee hasn't had lunch yet

A possible question might be: "Did you start your lunch yet?"

Did you think the question would be appropriate and grammatically correct? Would you use another expression? I want the most concise question possible (ideally no subordinates), and I also want it to be clear. Please note that the interviewees would be American not British.

I think other expressions such as "Have you had your lunch yet?" are not completely correct given my requirements.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had, or are you currently having lunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure from your question exactly what information you want. However, these are some possibilities:

- "Are you eating lunch right now?" = are you in the process of eating lunch at this moment, while you are answering this question?
- "Are you having lunch?" = somewhat ambiguous; it could mean "Are you eating lunch right now?" or it could mean, "Are you going to have lunch [later] today?" Therefore, you would need to add a time, such as, "Are you having lunch now?" or "Are you having lunch later today?"
- "Have you eaten lunch?" or "Have you had lunch today?" = did you eat lunch today (before this moment)?

Comment: I want to ask the interviewee if he/she has already started to eat his/her lunch

Comment: In that case, I would probably just ask them, "Have you started eating your lunch?"